# ng-class not working with certain condition

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

I have a code below.

```
<button class="button time-select-btn" ng-class="{'activated': input.load_time != 'nowload'}">time select</button>
<button class="button time-select-btn" ng-class="{'activated': input.load_time == 'nowload'}" ng-click="input.load_time = 'nowload'">nowload</button>
```

I want to create a button which when clicked, it returns input.load_time as 'now' and has class 'activated'.
The upper button works correctly(when input.load_time is not 'now', its class is 'activated'), however, the lower one does not work correctly(Even though the value of input.load_time is 'now', it does not have a class named 'activated'

EDIT:

I have tried below but didnt work.

```
<button class="button time-select-btn" ng-class="{'activated': input.load_time == 'nowload'}" ng-click="select_now_load()">nowload</button>
```

controllers.js

```
$scope.select_now_load = function(){
        $scope.input.load_time = 'nowload';
}
```

Comment: what is the `input`, does it exist in your scope?

Comment: Are you sure the `input.load_time` has the value 'nowload' ?

Comment: Have you initialised `input` as an object in your scope? If you haven't set it then the assignment to `input.load_time` will fail.

Comment: @Duncan I have initialized `input` as an object.

Comment: @Korte If I use `ng-click="input.load_time = 'nowload'"`, doesnt this set `input.load_time` as 'nowload'?

Comment: I would really appreciate it if you could create a plunker

Comment: @Korte I found the solution. It was because of class name `activated`. After I changed it to `time-activated`, I was able to get what I wanted. Thank you for the comment!